# Order in java arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I tried to sort an arraylist in java an it is a bit weird because the results is:[image]

This is the code for the sort part:

```
        int f=s.size();
        for(int i=0;i< f;i++)
        { for(int j=1;j<f;j++) {
            if (s.get(i) > s.get(j)) {

                int a = s.get(i);
                s.add(i + 1, s.get(j));
                s.remove(i);
                s.add(j + 1, a);
                s.remove(j);

                System.out.println(a);
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }

            }
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Comment: store vlaue at index i in temp variable and swap with value at j, s.remove(j), s.remove(i) , you will loose data permanently

Comment: I would recommend not using `add()` and `remove()` since those method shift the indices of the following elements which you'd have to handle correctly. Try `set(i, get(j))` and `set(j, a)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem was with the j in the second loop, you start always at one, what you wanted to do is start at i+1

also avoid using remove in a loop and continue looping in the array.

```
int f = s.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < f; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < f; j++) {
                if (s.get(i) > s.get(j)) {
                    Collections.swap(s,i,j);
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: than you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use bubble sorting which is one of the common sorting algorithms;

```
    int f = s.size(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < f-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < f-i-1; j++){ 
            if (s.get(j) > s.get(j+1)) 
            { 
               int temp = s.get(j);
               s.set(j, s.get(j+1)); 
               s.set(j + 1, temp);
            } 
         } }
```